# OpenXml. How to add creator using C# in docx?

Tags: c#, ms-word, openxml, docx, openxml-sdk

I am trying to add some core properties to the Docx document. I have found only one example in different places of how it can be done.

For instance [here](http://www.ericwhite.com/blog/forums/topic/how-to-set-the-documents-author-and-title/). But there is a problem.

If we look at the structure of the Docx itself created by Word application and using OpenXml, there is a difference between them.

[Structure of the docx created using openxml and document.PackageProperties.Creator = "vso"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BirQ3.png)

Moreover, validation of the file can't be succeeded if I want to check the file by productivity tool from Microsoft. Of course, the word can read this file, but it is not a proper way to generate a word file from my point of view.

[Here you can see the structure of the docx created by the word application itself](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q9A8P.png)

One more aspect, if I write following:

```
CoreFilePropertiesPart corePackageProperties = document.CoreFilePropertiesPart;
if (corePackageProperties == null)
{
   corePackageProperties = document.AddCoreFilePropertiesPart();
}
```

then core.xml file is created in the proper place of structure, but it is empty.

So, the question is does OpenXML SDK have the way to get the structure of the docx the same as using the word application itself?

Answer (score 0):

[Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/how-to-add-a-new-document-part-that-receives-a-relationship-id-to-a-package) suggests :

```
using (XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter(coreFilePropPart.GetStream(FileMode.Create), System.Text.Encoding.UTF8))
{
  writer.WriteRaw("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\r\n<cp:coreProperties xmlns:cp=\"https://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/metadata/core-properties\"></cp:coreProperties>");
  writer.Flush();
}
```

I had the same issue when creating an Excel file and this sort it out.